# Read from Hive tables and Write to Cassandra tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cassandra, cloudera, spark-cassandra-connector

I have some external tables in Hive in Cloudera cluster partitioned by `daily_date` column.

I also have DataStax Enterprise Cassandra cluster where I have created tables same as Hive tables structure.

Question: I want to export/write the tables data from Hive tables to the corresponding Cassandra tables.

Is there any Hive to Cassandra connector available? Or do I need to do this in Spark, if yes How? What would be the best practice/solution here?

I have tried to google a lot different keywords, but have not come across any correct/recommended solution.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/b2.5/doc), better with [Dataframe APIs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md).  Access data in Hive as [described in Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html), and after getting the dataframe, write it to Cassandra. Something like this:

```scala
// assuming that table is registered already:
val df = sql("SELECT * from hive_table")
df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "...", "keyspace" -> "..."))
  .save()
```